# create a file at launch of ec2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have a file `file.txt` in my local machine.

I want to create the same file with the same content automatically when the ec2 instance starts (let's say in the root directory for example).

There is the `UserData` parameter of the `create_instances` function that enables to execute a script automatically when the instance starts:

```
UserData = '''#/bin/bash
              echo "content" >> /file.txt'''
```

However this script will execute directly in the instance, so it can't know about `file.txt` in my local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ask yourself "How can a computer on the Internet access `file.txt` on my local machine?"

The answer, if you are following good security, is: "It can't!"

Instead, think about where you can place `file.txt` such that the EC2 instances *can* gain access. The easy answer is to place it in Amazon S3 and give the instances permission to access the file in Amazon S3.

The process would be:

- Create (or use an existing) Amazon S3 bucket
- Upload `file.txt` to the bucket
- When launching the EC2 instances, assign them an IAM Role that has permission to access `file.txt` in the bucket
- In the User Data script, copy the file from S3 to the instance

For example:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/file.txt file.txt
```

The file is then available on the EC2 instance.

In future, you can update `file.txt` in the S3 bucket. Any new instance will automatically retrieve the latest version of this file.